# Parsing form-data using Meteor

Tags: node.js, express, meteor, iron-router

I'm having an issue parsing multipart/form-data using Meteor

Here is my route:

```
this.route('mail', {
  where: 'server',
  path: '/mail',
  action: function () {
    console.log(this.request.body);
    this.response.end('get request\n');
  }
});
```

urlEncoded and JSON data work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in iron-router parsing multipart/form-data:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/909

Can solve in the meantime by using the Busyboy module:

```
var Busboy = Meteor.npmRequire("busboy")
var fs     = Npm.require("fs");
var os     = Npm.require("os");
var path   = Npm.require("path");

Router.onBeforeAction(function (req, res, next) {
  var filenames = []; // Store filenames and then pass them to request.

  if (req.method === "POST") {
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

    busboy.on("file", function (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
      var saveTo = path.join(os.tmpDir(), filename);
      file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
      filenames.push(saveTo);
    });

    busboy.on("field", function(fieldname, value) {
      req.body[fieldname] = value;
    });

    busboy.on("finish", function () {
      // Pass filenames to request
      req.filenames = filenames;
      next();
    });

    // Pass request to busboy
    req.pipe(busboy);
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```